Starting with CadQuery with some errors
Just starting with CadQuery and Python and making some errors.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cadquery as cq
  File "C:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\cadquery\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .occ_impl.shapes import (
  File "C:\Users\info\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\cadquery\occ_impl\shapes.py", line 19, in <module>
    from vtkmodules.vtkCommonDataModel import vtkPolyData
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtkmodules.vtkCommonDataModel'

and my coding is just simple.
import cadquery as cq
from cadquery.vis import show_object

height = 60.0
width = 80.0
thickness = 10.0

# make the base
result = cq.Workplane("XY").box(height, width, thickness)

# Render the solid
show_object(result)

Numpy 2.1.1
CadQuery 2.4.0
Do I need cq editor to view the screen? I didn't install it.
Any help is appreciated.
